# Flutter - Esta version no cumple el requisito de 64 bits de Google Play

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play

He desarrollado una pequeña aplicación con Flutter y como IDE: Android Studio, es mi primera subida a Google Play.

El caso es que me ha permitido subir lo que es la aplicación (como bundle) pesará unos 5,4MB pero no me deja publicarla por el error que muestro a continuación. No tengo ni idea de solventarlo, ya que me he metido en más información pero no saco algo en claro... 
¿Alguna idea?

Gracias stackeros :)

[image: Error que me muestra al subir la aplicación]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Agrega lo siguiente a tu app `build.gradle`:

   ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'

Quedara de esta manera:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "IdApp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

2. En la terminal corre `flutter clean`
3. Corre `flutter build apk --release --target-platform=android-arm`
4. Sube `app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk` a la Play Store
5. Incrementa el versionCode en el `pubspec.yaml`
6. Corre `flutter build apk --release --target-platform=android-arm64`
7. Sube `app-arm64-v8a-release.apk` a la Play Store

Comment: Ya lo solventé, pero sí, al final lo que me solventó el problema es tirar flutter clean y que compile la apk como arm64. Muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Como indicas que utilizas Android Studio como IDE para el desarrollo de tu app, deberías comprobar que en el fichero `build.gradle` tienes que también compile la versión de 64 bits de la app.

Fijate en la línea de "ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a',**'arm64-v8a'**,'x86',**'x86_64'**. Deberías tener las arquitecturas `arm64-v8a` y `x86_64`.

Mira como queda:

```
android {
       compileSdkVersion 27
       defaultConfig {
           appId "IdApp"
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 28
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
           ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

Una vez compilado, subes a Google Play las 2, la de 32 y 64 bits (o incluso te diría que solo la de 64 bits, hace tiempo que no subo ninguna app)...

Más info, [en la documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit?hl=es)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuida! cuando tenga un hueco pruebo lo que me comentas y te doy el feedback si me funciona :)

Comment: Perfecto, ya me dirás ;)

Comment: Buenas! He probado pero sin suerte, por lo que me han dicho en el grupo que tengo de Flutter España añadir el ndk.abifilters o no es indiferente por que el generar el bundle ya lo lleva "incorporado"
Sigo viendo a ver que opciones hay

Comment: Vaya... Pues a ver si alguien con más experiencia puede ayudar, yo hace la tira que no desarrollo ninguna app, pero si lo hago es a través de Visual Studio con Xamarin.Forms :)

Answer (score 0):

Solventado!

He compilado la app como apk para x64.
Es posible con el bundle pero finalmente he optado por la otra solución